# Remove border-right on :last-child psuedo-class

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

This is driving me nuts. I'm probably overlooking something super simple since I normally don't have issues with something like a psuedo-class.

I'm trying to remove the right border on a div element for the last-child. I can have it work with a class on the last element, but I don't need to do it that way (since the content will be in an ee loop).

Here is the code. Everything is wrapped in a section with an id of #small-featured. All the content that is nested in bootstrap columns is wrapped in a #featured-wrapper.

```
<section id="small-featured">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="featured-wrapper">
          <a href="#"><img src="assets/img/36-6022.png" alt=""></a>
          <p>The Product Title</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="featured-wrapper">
          <a href="#"><img src="assets/img/36-5100.jpg" alt=""></a>
          <p>The Product Title</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="featured-wrapper">
          <a href="#"><img src="assets/img/46-455.jpg" alt=""></a>
          <p>The Product Title</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="featured-wrapper">
          <a href="#"><img src="assets/img/unisaw.jpg" alt=""></a>
          <p>The Product Title</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Here is CSS

```
#small-featured {
  text-align: center;
}

#small-featured img {
  width: 250px;
  padding: 0 15px;
}

.featured-wrapper {
   border-right: 1px solid #eee;
}

#small-featured .featured-wrapper:last-child {
   border-right: none;
}
```

All the borders disappear when I add my last bit of CSS. I've tried targeting just .featured-wrapper:last-child as well.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
#small-featured .col-md-3:last-child .featured-wrapper {
  border-right: none;
}
```

(All `.featured-wrapper` are `:last-child`.) ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Great thanks! I was targeting .featured-wrapper instead of the last column child :)